# git: how to review changes done in branch

Tags: git, merge, git-merge

Consider the following situation:

Multiple branches - master, dev1..dev-n and feature1. Some development has occurred on feature1 branch (commits done to that branch) and I need to review them.

However...

1. Feature1 branch was split off master branch at some point in the past.
2. before merge into master, master was merged into Feature1 branch
3. Feature1(+master) were merged back into master.

So the graph looks something like this:

```
M F
|
g  (merge F to master)
|\
| \
f |
| 4 (last commit to F)
e |
| 3 (merge master to F - F contains commit b,c)
d/|
| 2
c |
| 1 (first commit to F)
b /
|/
a(base)
```

How do I see commits made directly to branch F (1-4) without seeing commits made to other branches and merged into F (a-g)?

Answer (score 1):

you can try this : `git log d..4`

it means all commits in `4` (a b c d 1 2 3 4) but not in `d` (a b c d) , the result is `1 2 3 4`

For more infomation about `Revision Selection`, visit [Revision Selection](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Revision-Selection)

Comment: how do I identify 4 and d? What if there are other merges from master to branch - e.g. e->3.5 (between 3 and 4)?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the customized solution using reflog:

```
git log --first-parent --no-merges $(git reflog feature1|tail -1|cut -d' ' -f1)..feature1
```

reflog gives all the updates to that branch reference, and tail gets only the first one(i.e. fork point), then we just cut SHA of the fork point.

Comment: reflog doesn't help me since the changes were done by other team members on their machines. I don't have their reflog to tell me what happened.